# Tensorflow : the placeholder after tf.split() cannot be accessed through another placeholder index variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, split

I have a tensorflow variable which is split using `tf.split`.

`Theta = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((R,s), dtype=tf.float64))

Theta_s = tf.split(Theta, ysplit, 1)`

`ysplit` is a list containing the length of split along axis 1. Now `Theta_s[i]` is a matrix of dimension (`R` x `ysplit[i]`). I have to access `Theta_s` through another placeholder index variable. Currently I am not able to do it since `tf.split()` returns the list and I get this error:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tensor`

Is there a suitable way to declare the variable to meet the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`tf.TensorArray`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray) to perform dynamic indexing with a `tf.Tensor`:

```
Theta_s = tf.split(Theta, ysplit, 1)

array = tf.TensorArray(tf.float64, size=len(Theta_s), clear_after_read=False)

for i, t in enumerate(Theta_s):
  array = array.write(i, t)

placeholder_index = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[])

Theta_s_i = array.read(placeholder_index)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the ysplit is a list of varying numbers, i.e, the split size is uneven. It seems that TensorArray expects the elements to be same shape. ysplit = [5,2,3]. The error is [ValueError: Inconsistent shapes: saw (3, 2) but expected (3, 5) (and infer_shape=True)].

Comment: Sorry.. My bad to miss the option. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Any suggestion to update a row of Theta_s_i : Theta_s_i[j], assuming Theta_s_i as a matrix? Thanks,